# PNP Powershell Updating Choice field

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, powershell, pnp-powershell

I have written a powershell script which reads off of a CSV and creates records in a list.
There are duplicate customer names within the CSV but they will have a different 'interested system' field.

On the list the interested system field is a choice with multiple choices allowed.

I have set the correct logic in the script to trigger if the record is a duplicate, If it is a duplicate only the 'Interested system' field will get updated.

The issue that i am facing is that when i use the code to update the Choice value of the field it is clearing the field and only adding the new choice. I am using a CAML query to do so.

Please see below script and please also ignore the commented parts. These were just my tests.

```
Function AddCustomerRecords($SiteURL,$ListName,$CSVPath,$IntentSignal)
{ 
#Remove-Variable PreviousValue -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

#Remove-Variable PreviousValue1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
#Read customer records from the CSV file
$CustomerData = Import-CSV $CSVPath 

 
$i = 0;
$TotalRecords = $CustomerData.Count

#Iterate through each row in the CSV and import it as a list item to the SPO List.
ForEach ($Record in $CustomerData)
{
$i++;
#$PreviousValue=$null;
#$PreviousValue1=$null;

#Remove-Item variable: PreviousValue
#Remove-Item variable: PreviousValue1
Write-host "Adding the record for company '$($Record.'Company Name')'" "$i out of $TotalRecords completed"

$CheckURL = $Record.'URL'
$HTTP = 'Http://'
$CheckDup = $Record.'Email'

if($CheckURL -notlike 'http*')
{

$CheckURL = "$HTTP$CheckURL"

Write-host 'Http has been appended onto the provided URL'

} 
else{
$CheckURL =$Record.'URL'

 }



#$ItemIDRef=  Get-PnPListItem -List $ListName -Fields "ID"


#$ItemIDRef1= $ItemIDRef.FieldValues.ID

$items2 = Get-PnPListItem -List $ListName -Query "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Email'/><Value Type='Text'>$CheckDup</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>"

#$previousvalues = Get-PnPListItem -List $ListName -Fields "InterestedSystem" 

#$items2 = Get-PnPListItem -List $ListName -Query "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Email'/><Value Type='Text'>$CheckDup</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>"


#$PREVid= Get-PnPListItem -List $ListName -Fields "ID"



#$PreviousSignal
if($items2)
{
ForEach ($PrevItem in $Items2)
{
#$PreviousValue1= $null

#$PREVid= Get-PnPListItem -List $ListName -Fields "ID"

#$PreviousValue= Get-PnPListItem -List $ListName -Fields "InterestedSystem" 

#$PreviousValue1= $PreviousValue.FieldValues.InterestedSystem


Write-host 'This Record already exists. Adding the Signal Intents'

Write-Host "$PreviousValue1"

Set-PnPListItem -List $ListName -Identity $items2 -Values @{"InterestedSystem" = "$IntentSignal"}

#Remove-Variable -Name PreviousValue
#Remove-Variable -Name PreviousValue1
}

}
else{


#Add List Item
Add-PnPListItem -List $ListName -Values @{
"Title" = $Record.'First Name';
"Last_x0020_Name" = $Record.'Last Name';
"CompanyName" = $Record.'Company Name';
"Email" = $Record.'Email'
"Role" = $Record.'Title'
"Phone" = $Record.'Phone'
"AddressLine1" = $Record.'Address Line 1'
"AddressLine2" = $Record.'Address Line 2'
"Address_x0020_Line_x0020_3" = $Record.'Address Line 3'
"PostalCode" = $Record.'PostalCode'
#"DirectPhone" = $Record.'Direct Phone'
"InterestedSystem" = $IntentSignal
"ContactMade" = "New"
"URL" = $CheckURL

};

}
 
}
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have attempted to save the previous value as a variable and then shoot it back in along side the choice but this seems to make the choices grow rapidly and is not working properly.

Thanks

Comment: Is the multi choice field or single choice field?

Comment: Hi Kalpesh it is a multi choice field

Answer (score 0):

You need to get existing field value for choice and append new values to it.

Use below code inside for each loop where you are updating item. It should work

```
    if($items2)
    {
        ForEach ($PrevItem in $Items2)
        {
            #$PreviousValue1= $null

            #$PREVid= Get-PnPListItem -List $ListName -Fields "ID"

            #$PreviousValue= Get-PnPListItem -List $ListName -Fields "InterestedSystem" 

            #$PreviousValue1= $PreviousValue.FieldValues.InterestedSystem

            
            $PreviousValue1 = ""
            Write-host 'This Record already exists. Adding the Signal Intents'

            Write-Host "$PreviousValue1"

            $prevValueColl = $PrevItem["InterestedSystem"]
            $isExist = $false
            foreach($prevValueChoice in $prevValueColl)
            {
               if($prevValueChoice -eq $IntentSignal)
               {
                  $isExist = $true;
               }
               $PreviousValue1 = $PreviousValue1 + ";" + $PreviousValue1
            }

            if($isExist -eq $false)
            {
                $PreviousValue1 = $PreviousValue1 + ";" + $IntentSignal
            }


            Set-PnPListItem -List $ListName -Identity $items2 -Values @{"InterestedSystem" = $PreviousValue1}

            #Remove-Variable -Name PreviousValue
            #Remove-Variable -Name PreviousValue1
        }

    }
```

Comment: Updated my answer as there was one mistake there

Comment: Hi Kalpesh, Thanks for your response. This script is still only adding the First IntentSignal and ignoring the second?

Comment: Can you add some write-host to show $PreviousValue1 and paste screen shot here?

Comment: After the write host the previous value is returning ;

Comment: Hey Kalpesh are you able to help?